# Confused with recursive methods & loops

Tags: java, for-loop, recursion, methods

I wrote the method below, but it doesn't work correctly.

Even if the pin is not correct, this program execute the next method in Main class.

The main idea is just when your pin is correct, than method will finished and the program go to the next method. If PIN isn't correct, than you will have 3 times. If all efforts were wrong, than the program will go out. So, your card will be blocked. Please, give me a peace of advise.

```
public boolean authenticity(short pin)  {
       if (pin == 1234) {
           System.out.println("PIN is correct");
           System.out.println("Card is active for operation!");
           return true;
       } else {
           pin = sc.nextShort();
           for (int i = 1; i >= 3; i++) {
               System.out.println("PIN isn't correct! You have " +i +"effort(s)");
               return authenticity(pin);  // recursion
           }
       }
       return false;
  }
```

*In the Main class the method is executed according to the command:
authenticity(sc.nextShort());

Comment: Can you show where you declare `sc`?

Comment: `for (int i = 3; i <0; i--)` your loop should have `i > 0`.

Comment: I think the title of this question should be changed. It doesn't have much about a boolean method, but rather recursion and an honest mistake with a loop.

Comment: In my case, I explain "sc"  @private final static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

Comment: I also did some correction, because I was mistaken and I used old version of my programm. My appologies!  @ for (int i = 1; i >= 3; i++)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method does not make a lot of sense...

Because you are trying to recursivly input the pin until the user make a correct input... then the `authenticity` will always return `true` or continue endlessy

Here's how the code works...
You need to call the `authenticity` method passing the number of retry before returning `false`.

If you don't have any more tries il will return `false` otherwise obtain a new pin and check for correctness...
If the number is not correct call recursively the `authenticity` decrementing by one the number of retries...

```
authenticity(3); // call the method passing 3 as max number of tries...

public static boolean authenticity(int tries) {
          if (tries > 0)
          {
           short pin = sc.nextShort();
           if (pin == 1234) {
               System.out.println("PIN is correct");
               System.out.println("Card is active for operation!");
               return true;
           } else {
               System.out.println("PIN isn't correct! You have " + tries +"effort(s)");
               return authenticity(--tries); 
           }
          } 
          return false;
      }
```

I removed the `for` because it didn't have much sense at all..

Comment: This is a bad answer. Your recursion has no break condition. The code in OPs question intents to allow only 3 retries.

Comment: Yaw you're right... I misinterpreted the code... I edited my own code to match the requirements...

Comment: How better implement a the break condition? I have two ideas: exception with try-catch structure or anonimous-intern class... What's your opinion?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, the loop's condition should be i > 0 :

```
       for (int i = 3; i > 0; i--) {
           System.out.println("PIN isn't correct! You have " +i +"effort(s)");
           return authenticity(pin);  
       }
```

Second of all, in your current implementation, each recursive call will give the user 3 additional attempts (at least until a `StackOverflow` occurs). You should pass the number of remaining attempts as a parameter to the recursive call. And you don't need a loop.

```
public boolean authenticity(short pin, int remainingAttempts) {
    if (pin == 1234) {
        System.out.println("PIN is correct");
        System.out.println("Card is active for operation!");
        return true;
    } else {
        pin = sc.nextShort();
        remainingAttempts--;
        if (remainingAttempts > 0) {
            System.out.println("PIN isn't correct! You have " +remainingAttempts +" attempts left");
            return authenticity(pin,remainingAttempts);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you wish to keep the loop, you can get rid of the recursion.

Comment: Also, get rid of the loop.

Comment: @mlk Yes, I just realized it myself.

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean authenticity(short pin, int tried) {
    if (pin == 1234) {
        System.out.println("PIN is correct");
        System.out.println("Card is active for operation!");
        return true;
    } else {
        pin = sc.nextShort();
        System.out.println("PIN isn't correct! You have " +tried +"effort(s)");
        if(tried==0)
            return false;
        return authenticity(pin,--tried);
    }
    return false;
}
```

use `tried == 3`; if you want more then use more

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing some key steps for recursion.  In this case it would probably be better to use simple iteration rather than recursion, and organize your code a bit better. It wasn't very clear if your scanner and such were local variables in another method, or fields, and your recursion was faulty as it never passed `i` (a field) when calling itself.

It seems that you're doing some scanner reads of the same thing in a different part of the code, which should all happen in the same place for organizational reasons:

```
public boolean authenticateUser(Scanner sc) {
   for(int tries = 0; tries<3; tries++){
       short attempt = sc.nextShort();
       if(attempt==1234) return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

If you still want to use recursion:

```
public boolean authenticateUser(short pin, int triesLeft) {
   if(triesLeft==0){
       System.out.println("You are out of tries.");
       return false;
   }
   if (pin == 1234) {
       System.out.println("PIN is correct");
       System.out.println("Card is active for operation!");
       return true;
   } else {
       pin = sc.nextShort();
       System.out.println("PIN isn't correct! You have " +i +"effort(s)");
       return authenticity(pin, triesLeft-1);  //it's recurcy
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run through how the code works. Assuming you fix up the loop.

```
authenticity(1):

public boolean authenticity(short pin) `{`
       if (pin == 1234) { // 1 == 1234 == FALSE
           System.out.println("PIN is correct");
           System.out.println("Card is active for operation!");
           return true;
       } else { // PASS
           pin = sc.nextShort(); // USER GETS TO TYPE SOMETHING NEW. Lets say "2"
           for (int i = 3; i > 0; i--) { // EXECUTES THE FOLLOWING THREE TIMES
           System.out.println("PIN isn't correct! You have " +i +"effort(s)"); // What does this print? Why?
           return authenticity(pin);  // EXCEPT RETURNS ON THE FIRST LOOP
           }
       }
       return false;
  }


authenticity(1):
  authenticity(2): 

public boolean authenticity(short pin) `{`
       if (pin == 1234) { // 2 == 1234 == FALSE
           System.out.println("PIN is correct");
           System.out.println("Card is active for operation!");
           return true;
       } else { // PASS
           pin = sc.nextShort(); // USER GETS TO TYPE SOMETHING NEW. Lets say "3"
           for (int i = 3; i > 0; i--) { // EXECUTES THE FOLLOWING THREE TIMES
           System.out.println("PIN isn't correct! You have " +i +"effort(s)"); // What does this print? Why?
           return authenticity(pin);  // EXCEPT RETURNS ON THE FIRST LOOP
           }
       }
       return false;
  }

authenticity(1):
  authenticity(2): 
    authenticity(3): 

public boolean authenticity(short pin) `{`
       if (pin == 1234) { // 3 == 1234 == FALSE
           System.out.println("PIN is correct");
           System.out.println("Card is active for operation!");
           return true;
       } else { // PASS
           pin = sc.nextShort(); // USER GETS TO TYPE SOMETHING NEW. Lets say "4"
           for (int i = 3; i > 0; i--) { // EXECUTES THE FOLLOWING THREE TIMES
           System.out.println("PIN isn't correct! You have " +i +"effort(s)"); // What does this print? Why?
           return authenticity(pin);  // EXCEPT RETURNS ON THE FIRST LOOP
           }
       }
       return false;
  }

authenticity(1):
  authenticity(2): 
    authenticity(3): 
       authenticity(4): 

public boolean authenticity(short pin) `{`
       if (pin == 1234) { // 4 == 1234 == FALSE
           System.out.println("PIN is correct");
           System.out.println("Card is active for operation!");
           return true;
       } else { // PASS
           pin = sc.nextShort(); // USER GETS TO TYPE SOMETHING NEW. Lets say "5"
           for (int i = 3; i > 0; i--) { // EXECUTES THE FOLLOWING THREE TIMES
           System.out.println("PIN isn't correct! You have " +i +"effort(s)"); // What does this print? Why?
           return authenticity(pin);  // EXCEPT RETURNS ON THE FIRST LOOP
           }
       }
       return false;
  }
```